# Cannot hide element when parent element is currently active with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a mini tab filter filter. The issue that i'm having is that when ever i'm on the current tab the "more" disappears on all the tabs. I don't want it to display when the page first loads because i want to show the content of the first tab. Also for some reason the class "current" isn't applied when the page first loads. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.tab').click(function() {
    var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');

    $('.iconsContainer').children().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    //hide "more" when you are currently on that tab
    $('.iconContainerMore').addClass('hideMoreText');

    $('.tripctychContent-container').children().hide();

    $('.tripctychContent-container').find("[data-blockid=" + tabID + "]").show();
  });

});
```

```css
.field--name-field-topic-2-content,
.field--name-field-topic-3-content {
  display: none;
}

.hideMoreText {
  display: none;
}

.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iconsContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tab p:first-of-type:hover {
  background: black;
}

.tab p:first-of-type {
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.current p:first-of-type {
  background: black !important;
}

.tripctychContent-container p {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iconsContainer">
  <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic1">
    <div>
      <p>Topic 1 title</p>
      <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic2">
    <div>
      <p>Topic 2 title</p>
      <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic3">
    <div>
      <p>Topic 3 title</p>
      <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="tripctychContent-container">
  <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content" data-blockid="topic1">
    <p>Topic 1 body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content" data-blockid="topic2">
    <p>Topic 2 body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content" data-blockid="topic3">
    <p>Topic 3 body</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding this to your selection will hide only the more of the tab clicked `$('.iconContainerMore', this).addClass('hideMoreText');` before you have to mark all more visible and then execute this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using the `closest()` to get the elements on click.

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {

  $('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideMoreText');
  $('.tab.current').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current').find('.iconContainerMore').addClass('hideMoreText');

  var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');
  $('.tripctychContent-container div').addClass('hideMoreText');
  $('.tripctychContent-container').find("[data-blockid=" + tabID + "]").removeClass('hideMoreText');

});
```

```css
.hideMoreText {
  display: none;
}

.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iconsContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.tab p:first-of-type:hover {
  background: black;
}

.tab p:first-of-type {
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.current p:first-of-type {
  background: black !important;
}

.tripctychContent-container p {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iconsContainer">
  <a class="tab current" data-tabid="topic1">
    <div>
      <p>Topic 1 title</p>
      <p class="iconContainerMore hideMoreText">More</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic2">
    <div>
      <p>Topic 2 title</p>
      <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic3">
    <div>
      <p>Topic 3 title</p>
      <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="tripctychContent-container">
  <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content" data-blockid="topic1">
    <p>Topic 1 body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content hideMoreText" data-blockid="topic2">
    <p>Topic 2 body</p>
  </div>
  <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content hideMoreText" data-blockid="topic3">
    <p>Topic 3 body</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't completely work. The "more" only needs to show on the non-active tabs(second and third).

Comment: so, if i click `tab1` then `tab2` and `tab3` should show more?

Comment: Actually when i implement into my website I have issues, because i have to use $('.tab') for the click function and not $('.tab div p). So how can i make it work when clicking on the tab class?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `this` to your jQuery selection will hide only the ***more*** in context of the tab clicked

```
$('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideMoreText');
$('.iconContainerMore', this).addClass('hideMoreText');
```

Note: Before you have to mark all ***more*** visible and then execute this

Snippet attached for reference

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.tab').click(function () {
    var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');

    $('.iconsContainer').children().removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    //hide "more" when you are currently on that tab
    $('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideMoreText');
    $('.iconContainerMore', this).addClass('hideMoreText');

    $('.tripctychContent-container').children().hide();

    $('.tripctychContent-container').find("[data-blockid=" + tabID + "]").show();
  });

});
```

```css
.field--name-field-topic-2-content, .field--name-field-topic-3-content  {
 display: none;
}

.hideMoreText{
  display: none;
}

.tab{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.iconsContainer{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
.tab  p:first-of-type:hover{
  background: black;
}
.tab p:first-of-type{
  padding: 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
.current p:first-of-type{
  background: black !important;
}
.tripctychContent-container p{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iconsContainer">
        <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic1">
            <div>
                <p>Topic 1 title</p>
                <p class="iconContainerMore hideMoreText">More</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic2">
            <div>
                <p>Topic 2 title</p>
                <p class="iconContainerMore hideMoreText">More</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic3">
            <div>
                <p>Topic 3 title</p>
                <p class="iconContainerMore hideMoreText">More</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="tripctychContent-container">
        <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content" data-blockid="topic1">
            <p>Topic 1 body</p>
        </div>
        <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content" data-blockid="topic2">
            <p>Topic 2 body</p>
        </div>
        <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content" data-blockid="topic3">
            <p>Topic 3 body</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when it doesn't completely work. When you first load the page all the "more" are visible, "more" only needs to show only on the non active tabs (second and last). Thanks!

Comment: @Charly you just have to init with hidemoretext class. check update

Comment: Going back to you first version of your code. What do you do to make the more each tab toggle? Because right now you can't show and hide based on click unless you click on another tab. I tried toggle with the 'hideMoreText' and also tried hiding the tab content, but couldn't get it to work. Can you please help?

Comment: Please see this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334812/jquery-toggle-class-not-working-correctly/58334994#58334994