# jQuery toggle class not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple tab filter, but I can't get it to work correctly. When the page first reloads i want the tab content to be hidden and I want the "more" to show on all the tabs, so far that's working. When you click on "more" the tab content should display, and "more" for that current tab should be hidden. I also need the tabs to toggle so i you click the tab again it should hide the tab content and show "more". Right now that issues that i'm having are that when you click on a tab the tab content of the other tabs show, but not the content of that tab, and also "more" doesn't show unless you click on another tab. Thanks!!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tab').click(function () {
        var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');
    
        $('.iconsContainer').children().removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    
        $('.tripctychContent-container').children().toggleClass('hideText');

        $('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideText');
        $('.iconContainerMore', this).toggleClass('hideText');
      
    
        $('.tripctychContent-container').find("[data-blockid=" + tabID + "]").toggleClass('hideText');
      });
      
  });
```

```css
.hideText{
  display: none;
}

.tab{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.iconsContainer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.tab  p:first-of-type:hover{
  background: black;
}
.tab p:first-of-type{
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
.current p:first-of-type{
  background: black !important;
}
.tripctychContent-container p{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
p{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="iconsContainer">
        <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic1">
          <div>
            <p>Topic 1 title</p>
            <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic2">
          <div>
            <p>Topic 2 title</p>
            <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic3">
          <div>
            <p>Topic 3 title</p>
            <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="tripctychContent-container">
        <div class="field--name-field-topic-1-content hideText" data-blockid="topic1">
          <p>Topic 1 body</p>
        </div>
        <div class="field--name-field-topic-2-content hideText" data-blockid="topic2">
          <p>Topic 2 body</p>
        </div>
        <div class="field--name-field-topic-3-content hideText" data-blockid="topic3">
          <p>Topic 3 body</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little change in your JS function in the end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tab').click(function () {
        var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');
        alert(tabID);

        $('.iconsContainer').children().removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $('.tripctychContent-container').children().toggleClass('hideText');

        $('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideText');
        $('.iconContainerMore', this).toggleClass('hideText');

        $('.field-class').hide()
        $("[data-blockid=" + tabID + "]").show();

      });      
  });
```

And have assigned a common class to all the tab content

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="iconsContainer">
    <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic1">
      <div>
        <p>Topic 1 title</p>
        <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic2">
      <div>
        <p>Topic 2 title</p>
        <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class="tab" data-tabid="topic3">
      <div>
        <p>Topic 3 title</p>
        <p class="iconContainerMore">More</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="tripctychContent-container">
    <div class="field-class hideText" data-blockid="topic1">
      <p>Topic 1 body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field-class hideText" data-blockid="topic2">
      <p>Topic 2 body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="field-class hideText" data-blockid="topic3">
      <p>Topic 3 body</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This almost works, that only issue that is left is that when you click on a tab you see the content of the other two tabs and not the content of the current tab :(. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `removeClass` explicitly if you are already using `toggleClass` for the same.

Answer (score 0):

**HERE!**

just update the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.tab').click(function () {
        var tabID = $(this).data('tabid');
        //alert(tabID);
        $('.iconsContainer').children().removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        //$('.tripctychContent-container').toggleClass('hideText');

        $('.iconContainerMore').removeClass('hideText');
        $('.iconContainerMore', this).toggleClass('hideText');
        $( ".tripctychContent-container>div").hide();
        $( ".tripctychContent-container>div[data-blockid=" + tabID + " ]" ).show();

        $('.tripctychContent-container').find("[data-blockid=" + tabID + "]").toggleClass('hideText');
      });

  });
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works, the only issue that is left is that when you click the same tab it doesn't hide "more" or the tab content :(. Please help me.